# first order pde

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

I wrote below code to solve a first order partial differential equation and find $p(k,t)$

```
Clear["Global`*"]
z := p[KK, t]
q := D[p[KK, t], t]
eqn = q + z Abs[KK]^a + I aa KK Pi  (E^(-t Abs[KK + 2 Pi/l]^a ) + 
E^(-t Abs[KK - 2 Pi/l]^a ) +  d/2  E^(-t Abs[KK 4 Pi/l]^a ) +  
d/2  E^(-t Abs[KK + 4 Pi/l]^a))/l == 0;
sol = DSolve[eqn, p[KK, t], {KK, t}]
Dsolve[eqn == 0, p, {KK, t}]
```

but after running the code, the answer is :

```
Abs[k]^a p[k, t] + q
```

Is there anyone here who knows what to do?

Comment: Mathematica is case sensitive.... e^( ) probably should be E^().

Comment: I corrected it, but still, there is the same problem. @bills

Comment: I see a pink mismatched ( in the middle of your eqn. It doesn't appear to even be able to handle Integrate[E^(-t k^a - I k x), {k, 0, Infinity}] so I am guessing it may not be able to give you a solution. Perhaps providing more information about a and t might help. This Integrate[
 E^(-t k^a - I k x), {k, 0, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] doesn't converge.

Comment: I change c to 1. Even in this case, it doesn't work @Bill

Comment: I change c to 1. Even in this case, it doesn't work @bills

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Perhaps Dsolve[eqn == 0, p, {k, t}] after correction for the closing missing parenthesis it gives {{p -> Function[{k, t}, E^(-t Abs[k]^a) C[1][k]]}}

Comment: I corrected the missing parenthesis in code, but ist still doesn't work. @cyrille.piatecki

Comment: What's the last line for? I guess `Dsolve` should be `DSolve`, but `eqn == 0` has the form `(lhs == 0) == 0`, which would seem nonsense to `DSolve`, since an equation can be `True` or `False` but never `0`. -- In any case, the first `DSolve[]` returns an answer for me in both V10.4.1 and V11.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was wrong. Copying our commands, on my computer

```
  Clear["Global`*"]
  z := p[KK, t]
  q := D[p[KK, t], t]
  eqn = q + z Abs[KK]^a + 
    I aa KK Pi (E^(-t Abs[KK + 2 Pi/l]^a) + 
    E^(-t Abs[KK - 2 Pi/l]^a) + d/2 E^(-t Abs[KK 4 Pi/l]^a) + 
    d/2 E^(-t Abs[KK + 4 Pi/l]^a))/l == 0;
   sol = DSolve[eqn, p[KK, t], {KK, t}]
```

I find

```
{{p[KK, t] -> -((
     I aa KK \[Pi] ((d E^(-(4 \[Pi])^a t Abs[KK/l]^a))/(
        Abs[KK]^a - (4 \[Pi])^a Abs[KK/l]^a) + (
        2 E^(-t Abs[KK - (2 \[Pi])/l]^a))/(
        Abs[KK]^a - Abs[KK - (2 \[Pi])/l]^a) + (
        2 E^(-t Abs[KK + (2 \[Pi])/l]^a))/(
        Abs[KK]^a - Abs[KK + (2 \[Pi])/l]^a) + (
        d E^(-t Abs[KK + (4 \[Pi])/l]^a))/(
        Abs[KK]^a - Abs[KK + (4 \[Pi])/l]^a)))/(2 l)) + 
    E^(-t Abs[KK]^a) C[1][KK]}}
```

Have you tried to close and reopen MA ?